# Можно ли изменить межстрочный интервал в QLabel

Tags: python, qt, pyqt5, qt-designer

Можно ли как то изменить межстрочный интервал в QLabel? Пробовал командой line-height, но ничего не изменилось.

Код:

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(640, 480)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.label_20 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label_20.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(150, 60, 321, 211))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Arial")
        self.label_20.setFont(font)
        self.label_20.setToolTipDuration(-1)
        self.label_20.setStyleSheet("line-height: 50%")
        self.label_20.setFrameShadow(QtWidgets.QFrame.Plain)
        self.label_20.setLineWidth(1)
        self.label_20.setMidLineWidth(0)
        self.label_20.setScaledContents(True)
        self.label_20.setWordWrap(True)
        self.label_20.setIndent(-1)
        self.label_20.setOpenExternalLinks(False)
        self.label_20.setObjectName("label_20")
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.menubar = QtWidgets.QMenuBar(MainWindow)
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 640, 21))
        self.menubar.setObjectName("menubar")
        MainWindow.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        self.label_20.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "<html><head/><body><p align=\"justify\"><span style=\" font-size:10pt;\">She </span><span style=\" font-size:10pt; font-weight:600;\">1) ----------------- </span><span style=\" font-size:10pt;\">(lie) in bed when she </span><span style=\" font-size:10pt; font-weight:600;\">2) ----------------- </span><span style=\" font-size:10pt;\">(hear) a sudden noise. She </span><span style=\" font-size:10pt; font-weight:600;\">3) ------------------- </span><span style=\" font-size:10pt;\">(open) her eyes in horror. Someone </span><span style=\" font-size:10pt; font-weight:600;\">4)
------------------ </span><span style=\" font-size:10pt;\">(open) a downstairs window; they </span><span style=\" font-size:10pt; font-weight:600;\">5) ----------------- </span><span style=\" font-size:10pt;\">(try) to get into her house. She </span><span style=\" font-size:10pt; font-weight:600;\">6) ------------------ </span><span style=\" font-size:10pt;\">(climb) slowly out of bed and </span><span style=\" font-size:10pt; font-weight:600;\">7)
----------------- </span><span style=\" font-size:10pt;\">(creep) to the door. She </span><span style=\" font-size:10pt; font-weight:600;\">8) -----------------</span><span style=\" font-size:10pt;\"> (stand) very still and listening carefully when she </span><span style=\" font-size:10pt; font-weight:600;\">9)
----------------- </span><span style=\" font-size:10pt;\">(see) a light downstairs. It </span><span style=\" font-size:10pt; font-weight:600;\">10) ----------------- </span><span style=\" font-size:10pt;\">(move) about as id someone </span><span style=\" font-size:10pt; font-weight:600;\">11)----------------- </span><span style=\" font-size:10pt;\">(hold) a torch and searching for something. She </span><span style=\" font-size:10pt; font-weight:600;\">12)
----------------- </span><span style=\" font-size:10pt;\">(know) that they </span><span style=\" font-size:10pt; font-weight:600;\">13)
----------------- </span><span style=\" font-size:10pt;\">(look) for her.</span></p></body></html>"))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    MainWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    ui = Ui_MainWindow()
    ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
    MainWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Укажите метку языка

Comment: пожалуйста, предоставьте [mcve]

Comment: Код прикреплен.